# Best way to assert that a value is not null

Tags: spring-boot, nullpointerexception, null-pointer

This is my method.

```
    public boolean authenticateAndPollCallbackResult(BankIdAuthRequest bankIdAuthRequest) {
            ResponseEntity<BankIdAuthResponse> authResponse = bankIdAuthentication(bankIdAuthRequest);
            AbstractApplicationForm applicationForm = applicationFormRepository.findByToken(bankIdAuthRequest.getRefID());
    
            try {
                //Add new bankId authentication to database.
                BankIdAuthenticationEntity bankIdAuthenticationEntity = new BankIdAuthenticationEntity();
                bankIdAuthenticationEntity.setAbstractApplicationForm(applicationForm);
                bankIdAuthenticationEntity.setAuthStatus(STATUS_PROGRESS);
                bankIdAuthenticationEntity.setOrderReference(authResponse.getBody().getOrderRef());
                bankIdAuthenticationEntity.setAutoStartToken(authResponse.getBody().getAutoStartToken());
    
                Long bankIdAuthenticationId = bankIdAuthenticationRepository.save(bankIdAuthenticationEntity).getId();
                BankIdAuthenticationEntity.AuthStatus authStatus;
    
                do {
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1500);
    
                    authStatus = getAuthStatus(bankIdAuthenticationId);
    
                    if (authStatus == BankIdAuthenticationEntity.AuthStatus.COMPLETED)
                        return true;
                    if (authStatus == BankIdAuthenticationEntity.AuthStatus.FAILED || authStatus == BankIdAuthenticationEntity.AuthStatus.NOT_ASSIGNED)
                        return false;
                } while (authStatus == BankIdAuthenticationEntity.AuthStatus.PROGRESS);
    
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.error("InterruptedException: ", e);
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                log.error("Either BankId API not responding correctly. Check server connection", e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception: Polling collect endpoint method failed", e);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Now SonarQube warns that these two lines can return null (and they can):

```
bankIdAuthenticationEntity.setOrderReference(authResponse.getBody().getOrderRef());
bankIdAuthenticationEntity.setAutoStartToken(authResponse.getBody().getAutoStartToken();
```

But i don't know what the best way to check for null is.
I tried using Objects.requireNonNull which throws a null and the i figured the null check would catch it but it just feel ugly and not correct.

Any suggestions or absolute correct ways of doing this that i might have missed?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `authResponse.getBody()` can be null. Right?

In this cas you should check it before an either throw an exception or not execute the two lines:

```
if(authResponse.getBody() != null {
    bankIdAuthenticationEntity.setOrderReference(authResponse.getBody().getOrderRef());
    bankIdAuthenticationEntity.setAutoStartToken(authResponse.getBody().getAutoStartToken();
})
```

or

```
if(authResponse.getBody() == null {
    throw new ....Exception();
}
```

And if the problem is that `getOrderRef()` or `getAutoStartToken()` could return null, you should check these values before and handle the cases when they are null.